# Orchard CMS Blog Home Page

Tags: blogs, orchardcms

I'm trying to set a blog as home page but it does not works.
I have 3 blogs, I have tried to set all of them and none works.
All blogs have some post in it.
I have customized blog post adding 2 extra fields (Image and Event Date)

I go to manage blog, I edit the blog, I tick "Set as home page".
Browsing site now in cassini I get a file list instead of the home page.

If I set back the home to a page all works.

My problem is that I do not want to see extra content: in my home page I just want to see a blog list.

I'm using Orchard 1.6 released version.
Nothing is shown in logs.
Settings_SiteSettingsPartRecord, HomePage column is always null (whatever page I set as Home, working or not working ones)

Possibile workaround:
show posts as widget and create a custom layout for home that hides content.
But I wondering why I cannot set a Blog as home page.
May it be related to Cassini?

Comment: Well, there is always the option of creating a projection but this should definitely work. Can you verify on a brand new install of Orchard, and if you can still reproduce it, file a bug? Thanks!

Comment: I have moved from cassini to iis express... now instead of directory listing i get the home page but instead of content i got "NOT FOUND
The page you are looking for does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have narrowed down the problem: the module that make blog fail as home page is Orchard.CulturePicker module from gallery.

For now I have just disabled it.

I have added an issue on culture picker project page:

https://orchardculturepicker.codeplex.com/workitem/38